# Insert into collection if checkbox input is checked

Tags: meteor, checkbox, semantic-ui

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm using a checkbox in a form that when checked and submitted using a button, it will create a new item in a collection.

Checkbox > Checked > Form Submit > Create new item in a collection.

Checkbox > Unchecked > Form Submit > Do not create the collection.

I have a collection Schema with the following:

```
value: {
    Type: Boolean, 
    ...
}
```

With a default of false. This is fine.

**What I have tried**
I have tried two different ways to pass this through to Meteor server side to insert the new collection:

- On change of checkbox, update DB value and on submit, check the value in db, if false, don't make collection, if true, make it.
- On submission of form, check if checkbox is checked or unchecked and create the new collection based on this.

Neither worked as I don't know how to pass the content from the HTML to the js file within Meteor. I know how to do this via JavaScript etc.

I'm using a simple `if(value) { }` but it seems this is only checking if the input exists and is always return true.

I've tried document.getelementbyID, this returns undefined on document. I've tried using it as an event, this returns that events is undefined.

**My question:**

How do I pass a checked/unchecked value into the Meteor Javascript?

Comment: maybe paste your codes so that we can see what you're doing/trying to do. Even though this is an extremely simple thing to do, probably nobody will answer unless you show your progress.

Comment: show us the form, helpers and events of the template, please.

Comment: @iiro I've done some reading and discovered a way that should do this. I'll update with an answer when I actually make progress.

Comment: @Luna Part of the problem was, I had no idea how to do this, but it seems using the `Template.template.events` I can achieve this using a `click` event to update the database and subsequently perform a statement on the DB.

Comment: @Dandy Exactly. shoot me another comment reply with your new codes in template events if you can't make it work. cheers

Answer (score -1):

You can pass any value into the server side by submitting the form or using an ajax request. I think your question is how to get the checkbox' status: checked or unchecked, am I correct?

So, if you're using jQuery, you can get it with one call:

```
$(":checkbox").prop("checked");
```

And if you're using the original js：

```
document.getElementById("checkboxId").checked;
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: As mentioned, for whatever reason I can't perform a check in the DOM using document.getElementByID. For some reason ( I don't know why) I received an error  along the lines of 'document is not defined'. This is likely a misunderstanding on my part because I don't fundamentally understand Meteor fully.